# Need to format time zone offset using moment js

Tags: momentjs

I have a datepicker on my page, when I select any date it produced a result something like

```
Sun Sep 07 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
```

And I need to format it: `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss Z`

So, for this I use moment syntax

```
var date='Sun Sep 07 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)';
moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss Z');
```

which produces an output

```
2014-09-07T00:00:00 +05:00
```

That's good, but my api expect standard timezone offset 'Z' instead of parsing into local current time zone (i.e +5:00) in my case.

So, I want to produce this

```
2014-09-07T00:00:00Z
```

How is it possible?

Comment: just concat Z `moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss') + 'Z';`

Comment: Are you picking a whole date? or a date + time?  What does the API expect?  Adjusting for UTC makes sense when a time is involved, but not necessarily when it's just a date.

Comment: Yes, I m picking a whole date. My API expect a date (eg: 2014-09-07T00:00:00Z). It actually not expect any offset, it just require 'Z' after second. I know this can be achieved by concatenation, just wondering if moment produce itself as well.

Answer (score 17):

Use [moment.utc()](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/)  to display time in UTC time instead of local time:

```
var dateValue = moment(date).utc().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss') + 'Z';
```

or `moment().toISOString()` to display a string in [ISO format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (format: `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`, the timezone is always UTC):

```
var dateValue = moment(date).toISOString();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1n952z71/)

Comment: While this is true, it will shift the time to UTC as well, and I *think* the OP wants either a whole date, or a date+time at UTC midnight.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using a hard-coded format string and then concatenating the 'Z' after it, it would be better to just use the `toJSON()` function which has been around since moment js v2.0. Like so:

```
moment('Sun Sep 07 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)').toJSON();
```

Here's the complete [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hazkzrdq/).

Comment: Was it supposed to be 19h?